# Throwing an exception from the constructor of an exception in C++

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, throw

Note that this question has to do with throwing an exception from the constructor *of an exception class*, not from any old constructor.  I was not able to find a duplicate question on stackoverflow.

[This article](http://www.acodersjourney.com/2016/08/top-15-c-exception-handling-mistakes-avoid/) recommends against throwing such an exception, but I am suspicious of the technical reason given (and the author seems to backtrack on the reason in the comments).

I will give an example and then discuss my interpretation of what's happening, which implies that there basically shouldn't be a problem with doing this, at least from a technical point of view.  My main question is whether my interpretation is correct, or if I am missing something conceptually.

**Example:** Suppose that I want to divide all possible exceptions into two types, `User_Error` and `Coder_Error`.  The former indicates, obviously, that the user did something that they weren't supposed to, and the latter indicates that some serious internal check failed and that someone should file a bug report.  Here is a (obviously oversimplified) sketch:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
...

class Coder_Error : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    Coder_Error( const std::string& msg ) :
       std::runtime_error( msg + "  Please freak out and file a bug report!" )
    {}
};


class User_Error : public std::runtime_error
{
protected:
    static void check_state() const
    {
        ...  // May rely on static members of this class or other classes.
        if ( validation_failed ) {
            throw Coder_Error( "A useful description of the problem." );
        }
    }

public:
    User_Error( const std::string& msg ) : std::runtime_error( msg )
    {
        check_state();
    }
};
```

Now suppose that I do `throw User_Error( "Some useful message." );` in a case where `User_Error::check_state()` will throw.  What will happen?

**Interpretation:** My expectation would be that the `Coder_Error` object will get thrown before the `throw` in `throw User_Error( "Some useful message." )` line is ever encountered, and therefore we do not have to worry about two exceptions being thrown simultaneously, or anything like that.  To be more explicit, I expect the relevant steps to occur in something like the following order.

1. `User_Error::User_Error` will get called.
2. `User_Error::check_state` will get called.
3. `Coder_Error::Coder_Error` will get called.
4. The `Coder_Error` object created in step 3 will get thrown.
5. Stack unwinding will commence and ordinary execution will be stopped, so the execution will never get to a point where it could `throw` the `User_Error` created in step 1.  (I am assuming that no errors are getting caught.)

Is this correct?

Comment: Not saying it's impossible, but I have a hard time thinking of an actual case where it's desirable to purposefully hide an exception with one of a different kind *sometimes* .

Comment: If `Coder_Error` is meant to represent a programming error, then it may be more intuitive to inherit from [`std::logic_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) as it's more representative of the situation. `std::runtime_error` is associated with an unexpected situation where as `std::logic_error` is associated with a programming error and is harder and less often recovered from.

Comment: If you have something that looks like `throw User_Error ();` and `User_Error` throws, expect a bumpy ride. I would not do this.

Comment: I'm not sure if it qualifies but [\[except.throw\]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/except.throw#7) might be relevant here.

Comment: If you want to throw a type that potentially throws itself then please name it accordingly ... `throw up();`

Comment: @NathanOliver My question is basically whether that actually occurs, i.e., whether two exceptions are simultaneously being thrown, or just one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux @user4581301 Sure, I agree that my example is contrived and possibly a bad idea for other reasons.  But it doesn't answer my question of whether it is "safe" to do so, in the limited sense of being defined behavior, not immediately invoking `std::terminate()` because two exceptions are being thrown simultaneously, etc.

Comment: @sasquires Yeah.  After looking at everything I agree with Brian's answer.  It looks like you are okay.

Comment: My problem with doing this has nothing to do with whether it is safe or correct. It promotes unforced errors as the programmer has to figure out why they threw one exception and either caught and handled something else or did not catch the exception at all. You need a really good reason to do something like this.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand your concern, and this is the reason why my original post contained sentences such as "My main question is whether my interpretation is correct, or if I am missing something conceptually." *The question is not about the example.* The example only exists to illustrate the conceptual issues involved in the question. (I spent 30 seconds contriving this example. Before posting, I had considered doing this in a situation that was considerably more complex, but I had already decided not to do it.  I posted because it raised a question about my understanding of C++ itself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're correct that evaluating `throw User_Error(...)` has a well-defined result and does not call `std::terminate`, provided that the `Coder_Error` object is caught by an enclosing handler. [GCC and Clang both agree](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33ab5da7278be2fb).

Your reasoning is correct for C++14 and below. In C++17, due to mandatory copy elision, the constructor of `User_Error` is called during the process of throwing the exception, *i.e,* once the compiler has already started evaluating the `throw` part and has allocated some storage somewhere for the exception object. However, when the construction exits *via*  second exception, the compiler cleans up that storage and proceeds to look for a handler for the second exception. In either case, the result is as you say.

Note that `std::terminate` will be called if the copy constructor called during *handling* of the exception exits *via* an exception (*i.e.,* as the exception object is being copied into a handler that catches by value) ([see example](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#throw-7)). This is distinct from the situation you have described.

Comment: I've found a standard section if you want to include it that actually calls this out: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/except.special#except.terminate-1.1

Comment: @NathanOliver Notes are non-normative. The paragraph I linked to is the normative one for this rule.